# Получить путь к файлу/папке из элемента дерева

Tags: c#, wpf

```
{
   // string path;
   // string path1;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
            item.Tag = drive;
            item.Header = drive.ToString();
            item.Items.Add("*");
            tree.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void treeView_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;         
            item.Items.Clear();            
            tree.SelectedItemChanged += Tree_SelectedItemChanged;
            TreeViewItem sItem;
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs;
            FileInfo[] files = null;
            if (item.Tag is DriveInfo)
                dirs = new DirectoryInfo(item.Header.ToString()).GetDirectories();
            else
            {
                dirs = ((DirectoryInfo)item.Tag).GetDirectories();
                files = ((DirectoryInfo)item.Tag).GetFiles();
            }
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
            {
                sItem = new TreeViewItem();
                sItem.Header = dir.ToString();
                sItem.Tag = dir;
                sItem.Items.Add("*");
                item.Items.Add(sItem);
            }
            if (files != null)
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                    item.Items.Add(file);               
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

    private void Tree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {          

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если отринуть напрашивающиеся замечания по поводу ООП и MVVM и попробовать решить проблему с использованием подхода, заданного автором, получится что-то такое.

XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeView"
          TreeViewItem.Expanded="OnTreeViewItemExpanded"
          SelectedItemChanged="OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
```

Здесь всё очевидно за исключением включения виртуализации - для папок с большим количеством файлов данный код знатно подтормаживает без виртуализации.

Codebehind:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                var dir = drive.RootDirectory;
                TreeView.Items.Add(GetDirNode(dir));
            }
        }

        private void OnTreeViewItemExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;
                item.Items.Clear();
                var dirs = ((DirectoryInfo)item.Tag).GetDirectories();
                var files = ((DirectoryInfo)item.Tag).GetFiles();

                foreach (var dir in dirs)
                {
                    item.Items.Add(GetDirNode(dir));
                }
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    item.Items.Add(GetFileNode(file));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

        private TreeViewItem GetNode(FileSystemInfo info)
        {
            var result = new TreeViewItem();
            result.Header = info.ToString();
            result.Tag = info;
            return result;
        }

        private TreeViewItem GetFileNode(FileInfo fileInfo)
        {
            return GetNode(fileInfo);
        }

        private TreeViewItem GetDirNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
        {
            var result = GetNode(directoryInfo);
            result.Items.Add("*");
            return result;
        }

        private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(((e.NewValue as TreeViewItem).Tag as FileSystemInfo).FullName);
        }
```

Основное изменение к оригинальному коду - переход на хранение во всех узлах дерева `TreeViewItem`, у которого в свойстве `Tag` лежит тот или иной `FileSystemInfo` (предок `FileInfo` и `DirectoryInfo`). Это позволяет единообразно получать директорию для любого узла дерева вне зависимости от того, является ли узел диском, папкой или файлом. Проблема с отображением ненужной кнопки-экспандера для файлов решается путем недобавления детей для узла файла.

Если будут какие-то вопросы, отвечу обязательно.

Comment: Не понятно, как получаем путь (e.NewValue as TreeViewItem).Tag as FileSystemInfo).FullName. Почему используется несколько свойств, вместо одно fullname

Comment: Вообще касательно этой строки, не совсем понятно использование конструкции as

Comment: @SOFL используется не несколько свойств разом. эта запись - каскад приведений типов и выбора их свойств. Грубо говоря, она развернётся в [это] (https://gist.github.com/dmdymov/4bfc5640f87e46489318468a1925f957). Конструкция as - это оператор "мягкого" явного приведения типов, который не выбрасывает исключение при невозможности приведения, а просто возвращает null. Пример с описанием работы [тут](https://gist.github.com/dmdymov/bc3663d8994ec1f4048e151ec32fe03a).

Comment: @SOFL эта строка может быть записана в том числе через явные приведения как **((FileSystemInfo)((TreeViewItem)e.NewValue).Tag).FullName**, может быть в таком виде понятнее.